# How to use NpgsqlParameter with ExecuteSqlCommand to avoid injection attacks? Getting NpgsqlException Error 42601: syntax error at or near \"(\""

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I am using Entity Framework with PostgreSQL, which means I'm using Npgsql as the data provider. I would like to call `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` to make a query, and I'm trying to use parameters to avoid injection attacks. One example of a query I would like to make is alter table add column. Here is what my code looks like to set up the parameters and the sql query:

```
NpgsqlParameter tableNameParam = new NpgsqlParameter("tableName", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
tableNameParam.Value = entityTableName;
NpgsqlParameter fieldNameParam = new NpgsqlParameter("fieldName", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
fieldNameParam.Value = sqlFieldName;
NpgsqlParameter fieldTypeParam = new NpgsqlParameter("fieldType", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
fieldTypeParam.Value = sqlType;

object[] sqlParams = {tableNameParam, fieldNameParam, fieldTypeParam};

string addColumnQuery = "ALTER TABLE @tableName ADD @fieldName @fieldType";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(addColumnQuery, sqlParams);
```

When I run this I catch an NpgsqlException with

> error 42601: syntax error at or near \"(\"".

I looked into the stack trace and found that the ErrorSQL displays:

> "ALTER TABLE (('dbo.person_entity')::text) ADD (('name')::text)(('varchar')::text)"

As you can see the query went horribly wrong. In my test I am using a person entity and adding a column "name" with type "varchar". I just want the query to be like this:

> "ALTER TABLE dbo.person_entity ADD name varchar"

But for some reason using NpgsqlParameters is messing that up. I suspect it has to do with the `NpgsqlDbType.Text` but it seems like the NpgsqlParameter constructor requires a type as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, PostgreSQL doesn't support parameters for column/table names. There are some good reasons for this behavior: it doesn't normally make sense to allow users to create arbitrary fields with arbitrary types in your databases - even if you sanitize them to prevent SQL injection. Try to think of redesigning your application.

For a more technical explanation of what's happening in your case, the Npgsql Entity Framework provider replaces your parameter placeholder (e.g. @fieldName) with a *text literal* - and (('dbo.person_entity')::text) is a perfectly valid literal. The problem is that column names and types aren't text literals: you don't surround them with quotes.

Comment: But why is it perfectly fine for SQL Server then? I've had no problem doing it with that. It just seems like such a bizarre thing to prevent the developer from doing. If the developer wants to take that risk, shouldn't it be allowed? Anyway, I appreciate the explanation. The whole application is based around users creating their own tables (well, on the backend -- they don't actually know that), so I guess I have to risk injection attacks.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use NpgsqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier() to escape your strings, this should prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm kind of confused about how to use it though. Sorry I'm kind of new to this sort of stuff. I found [the code for NpgsqlCommandBuilder](http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/download.php/1000140/593/1010700/423/NpgsqlCommandBuilder.cs) but I'm not sure how QuoteIdentifier helps here. Do you have an example of how I would use it with `Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`? Or is the point of it that I'm supposed to initialize an `NpgsqlDataAdapter` and use an Npgsql command rather than doing the generic `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`? Thanks

Comment: That was a bad suggestion, I take it back, QuoteIdentifier will add quotes around your string, which is exactly what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: No problem. It turns out I should be safe. There was a certain piece of context I hadn't thought about when writing this question. If you're curious, it's because each user input is restricted to this regex `[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*` (lowercase and uppercase letters, and numbers), so an injection attack should be impossible.