# PostgreSql & Entity Framework 6.0 - call stored procedure from specific schema

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I need to call existing stored procedure from postgres database. I do it in this way:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var param = new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("_code", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
    param.Value = "01";
    var statusId = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("mfd.get_id_status", param).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But above code throws an exception: **ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near \"mfd\"**

I can get data by LINQ from my database so connection is ok. I'm sure that schema `mfd` and `get_id_status` exists.

What I'm doing wrong with my calling procedure from DB?

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869818/how-to-use-npgsqlparameter-with-executesqlcommand-to-avoid-injection-attacks-ge

Comment: @mcNets: I saw that before and it wouldn't help me.

Comment: TEMPORARY SOLUTION: at the moment I do just `var statusId = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select mfd.get_id_status('01')").FirstOrDefault();` but it's workaround and if I find fix for it I will post it here.

Comment: TEMPORARY SOLUTION #2: for functions which returns complex type (e.g. table) you have to change above line to: `var status = db.Database.SqlQuery<StatusViewModel>("SELECT * FROM mfd.get_status('5')").FirstOrDefault();`
The key is using `select * from function()` instead of `select function()`.